# innerHTML not showing hyperlink

Tags: javascript, countdown

I built a countdown function in js, the div shows the seconds that left to show the skip button, but the innerHTML only showing text so the link is not clickable.

the countdown function:

```
  <div id="strclock"> Clock Here!</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var hour = <?php echo floor($hours); ?>;
    var min = <?php echo floor($minutes); ?>;
    var sec = <?php echo floor($seconds); ?>;
    var skip = "<a href='google.com'><img src='images/delicious_32.png'/></a>";

    function countdown() {
        if(sec <= 0 && min > 0) {
            sec = 59;
            min -= 1;
        }else if(min <= 0 && sec <= 0) {
            min = 0;
            sec = 0;
        }else {
            sec -= 1;
        }
        if(min <= 0 && hour > 0) {
            min = 59;
            hour -= 1;
        }

        var pat = /^[0-9]{1}$/;
        if(min > 0 || hour > 0){
            sec = (pat.test(sec) == true) ? '0' + sec : sec;
        }
        min = (pat.test(min) == true) ? '0' + min : min;
        hour = (pat.test(hour) == true) ? '0' + hour : hour;

        document.getElementById('strclock').innerHTML = ".המתן " + sec + " שניות";
        setTimeout("countdown()",1000);

        if(sec <= 0){
            document.getElementById('strclock').innerHTML = skip;
        }
    }

 countdown()
</script>
```

I tried with jquery append() function and few other javascript functions but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a function to as first parameter to the document.setTimeout
Try this: `setTimeout(countdown,1000);`

Comment: well, that part of the code works, `document.getElementById('strclock').innerHTML = skip;` thats the thing that not working, its showing me the picture but its not clickable